# Not able to find the value of a textbox from DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium

I have the below input tag for a textbox. The value is getting displayed in
UI but I am not able to retrieve it from DOM. Any suggestions how we can extract the value from the below tag

```
<input id="f_aDE8F92F6A8E345D19EB6A819D317DFA89AF_3_1" 
       class="x-form-text x-form-field dct-field x_normalBG x-form-focus" 
       size="14" 
       autocomplete="off" 
       fieldref="ClientConsiderationsAL.LinesOfInsuranceOfTheClientWithABC" 
       objectref="aDE8F92F6A8E345D19EB6A819D317DFA8" maxlength="14" 
       name="int_9AF" title="" type="text"/>
```

Comment: please show how you are retrieving the value

Comment: if you are using angular it should retrieve by modal

Comment: We are automating using Selenium and the application is built with AngularJS...normally there will be a value attribute with which we can extract the value..but in this case it is different

Comment: I don't see any presence of **value** _attribute_ for the `<input>` tag. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using angularjs add ng-model="relevant-name" to the input and in the controller add $scope.relevant-name as a variable to bind to like this: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_model.asp

If it's just javascript then you need to do something like this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/wU13Bnd6j3TRfYcNV9ZG?p=preview

```
<input id="f_aDE8F92F6A8E345D19EB6A819D317DFA89AF_3_1" 
class="x-form-text x-form-field dct-field x_normalBG x-form-focus" 
size="14" 
autocomplete="off" 
fieldref="ClientConsiderationsAL.LinesOfInsuranceOfTheClientWithABC" 
objectref="aDE8F92F6A8E345D19EB6A819D317DFA8" maxlength="14" 
name="int_9AF" title="" type="text" onkeyup="textChanged()"/>

<script>
 function textChanged() {
  var input = 
  document.getElementById('f_aDE8F92F6A8E345D19EB6A819D317DFA89AF_3_1');
  console.log(input.value);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks..it's working. Even though the value attribute is not present in the tag but if we do elementId.getAttribute("value") it works